# Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't work only when released

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging in my Flutter app and in most cases it seems to work. I can receive notifications in my app when:

- using `flutter run`
- using `flutter run --release`
- using Xcode's Product > Run

all targeting my iPhone that's linked to the computer. I am using flavors (dev, qa, prod), and it works across all flavors.

**When it doesn't work is when I package it up for Firebase App Distribution or Testflight. It's easier focus on App Distribution, so I'll address what I've done there.**

In setting up messaging, I have enabled push notifications in XCode (I originally had the problem of hitting the development APNs, but I changed the configuration to use the production service). Here's my entitlement file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.applesignin</key>
    <array>
        <string>Default</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
    <array>
        <string>applinks:N/A</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And Background Modes are enabled in the Info.plist file as well:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

I have a key created in the Apple Developer Portal as required:
[image: Apple Developer Portal key]

And I have that uploaded into Firebase as required:
[image: Firebase key configurtion]

When deploying to App Distribution, I run the following commands:

```
flutter build ios --flavor <env>
cd ios
xcodebuild -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme <env> archive -archivePath Runner.xcarchive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath Runner.xcarchive -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist -exportPath ../build/ios -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

where  is one of my flavors, as mentioned above and my exportOptions.plist is

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>compileBitcode</key>
    <false/>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>ad-hoc</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I'm happy to provide more clues, configurations, explaination, but right now, I'm at a loss as to what's missing and could be causing this behavior. So the question is, why do push notification not work when deployed through an archive?

Comment: I should note that, yes, I'm using firebase_messaging 7.0.3. I know there's a dev release that is a fairly large overhaul, but since I'm going to production, well, yesterday, I can't put a non-production build in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: I was missing `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()` in my AppDelegate.swift.

Looks like my AppDelegate.swift would have been helpful to post:

```
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    let controller : FlutterViewController = window.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let flavorChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "flavor", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    flavorChannel.setMethodCallHandler({ (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
        result(Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["Flavor"])
    })
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

We had implemented the directions according to the README in the firebase_messaging project (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging). This necessitated adding `if #available` lines. Yes, this is only for doing method swizzling, and we weren't (i.e. we didn't have `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` in our Info.plist file), but I stumbled upon [Flutter FCM on iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172280/flutter-fcm-on-ios-14) (they are implementing swizzling), and noticed that they had an extra line in their file: `application.registerForRemoteNotifications()`. Once I added that line, (on the line before the return), push notifications started working.